# the system.input.read() != -1 loop never stop

Tags: java, while-loop, java-io

I was writing a piece of code that takes an input string and outputs only the chosen chars. I'm asked to use system.input.read otherwise I'll just settle with scan or something similar. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i;
        String answer = "";

        while ((i = System.in.read()) != -1) {
            if (i == 65 || i == 67 || i == 71 || i == 84) {
                answer = answer + (char)i;
            }
            //System.out.println(answer);
        }
        //System.out.println(answer);
    }

}
```

if I put

```
 System.out.println(answer);
```

within the while loop, it print stuff, but the same statement does nothing outside the while loop, even if I initiate the string with "12345" -- the print statement will never be executed if it is not in the loop. So, to the best of my knowledge, there can be only one problem: the loop never stopped.

But the loop is supposed to stop after it reach the last item in the input string. the

```
System.input.read()
```

method is suppose to return -1 after all entry has been read and end the loop (I put `i != -1` as the end condition), but apparently it doesn't.

Could anyone please explain to me what I did wrong and why this is wrong. It's so weird, and I never want to have the same problem ever again.

Comment: "*`read`: [returns] the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.*" AFAIK, `stdin` is open until you explicitly close it. You don't.

Comment: It's terminal dependent but I believe IntelliJ on Windows, CTRL + D will close the input stream.

Comment: `System.in` is still opened so there is a chance that user will write some value later. In that case application needs to wait for any data from user or until `System.in` will be closed. "*I'm asked to use system.input.read*" but WHY? Is this some kind of punishment?

Comment: you can run your application with  "< inputfile" at the end, then input.read() will eventually finish